# How can I get a specific div from website?

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I am trying get a specific div element (i.e. with attribute `id="vung_doc"`) from a website, but I get almost every element. Do you have any idea what's wrong?

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://lightnovelgate.com/chapter/epoch_of_twilight/chapter_300');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//*[@class='vung_doc']";


$entries = $xpath->query($query);
var_dump($entries->item(0)->textContent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it appears that that one element, which has both **id** and **class** attributes with value *vung_doc*, has many paragraphs inside its text content. Perhaps you are thinking each paragraph should be in its own *div* element.

```
<div id="vung_doc" class="vung_doc" style="font-size: 18px;">
    <p></p>
    "Mayor song..."
```

In the screenshot at the bottom of this post, I added an outline style to that element, to show just how many paragraphs are within that element.

If you wanted to separate the paragraphs, you could use [preg_split()](http://php.net/preg_split) to split on any new line characters:

```
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach($entries as $entry) {
    $paragraphs = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/s",$entry->textContent);
    foreach($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
        if (trim($paragraph)) {            
            echo '<b>paragraph:</b> '.$paragraph;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

See a demonstration of this [in this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/dwRNYvMEscp3ZRNW). Note that before loading the HTML file, [libxml_use_internal_errors()](http://php.net/libxml_use_internal_errors) is called, to suppress the XML errors:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

Screenshot of the target **div** element with outline added:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$query = "//*[@class='vung_doc']";
```

to

```
$query = "//*[@id='vung_doc']";
```